# How to update or drop @CompoundIndex with Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, compound-index

I have existing @CompoundIndex defined like:

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "idx_test_search", unique = true,
        def = "{type: 1, origin: 1, date: 1}")
```

And now i need to changed it to add another field like:

```
@CompoundIndex(name = "idx_test_search", unique = true,
        def = "{type: 1, origin: 1, date: 1, travelers: 1}")
```

I expected this to be applied automatically like it was created on app start, but in the MongoDb it remains the same old one. I can create a different index with new name but then I need to drop this one. Can I do it with `@ChangeSet`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to this with mongoTemplate and @Changeset:

```
@ChangeLog(order = "0.0.1")
public class MongoChangelogVersion_0_0_1 {

    @ChangeSet(order = "0001", id = "testSearchIndex", author = "djordje.ivanovic@****.com")
    public void dropIndex(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) throws IOException {
        List<IndexInfo> indexes =  mongoTemplate.indexOps(TestSearch.class).getIndexInfo();
        for(IndexInfo indexInfo: indexes){
            if(indexInfo.getName().equals("idx_test_search")){
                mongoTemplate.indexOps(TestSearch.class).dropIndex("idx_test_search");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*mongoTemplate.indexOps(TestSearch.class)* is returning a list of all indexes for related table (TestSearch in my case), so after checking if index exists, we will drop it.